# iPad Pro reporting wrong screen scale

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

The call to get the device screen scale:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
```

does not return the proper value for the iPad Pro. The device is reporting 2, when it should be higher.

Other answers insist it's an issue of whether we are using a Launch Screen. Our project uses both a Launch Images asset catalog and a storyboard Launch Screen. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) iPad Pro has @2x screen scale so 2 is correct value actually.

Comment: Isn't it internally scaling it up or something?  I am having an issue where on the iPad Pro only, I get some aliasing with a sub-pixel-sized border.  I was hoping to detect the scale and adjust, but so far that isn't working for me, hrm...